# draw.io / diagrams.net - current date in a text field?

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

Is it possible to enter a variable of some sort in a text field in my diagram that has the current date and will auto-update to the current date whenever I edit the diagram again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to try %date% placeholder as described here:
https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/predefined-placeholders

Placeholder should be ticked under Edit data: https://www.diagrams.net/blog/placeholders